# Github pages URL redirecting to old custom domain

Tags: redirect, dns, github-pages

Currently hosting a site on Github pages. I had it redirecting to a custom domain, then decided to switch domains. I changed the CNAME file in the repository to reflect the new domain, but when I go to my Github pages URL (user.github.io) it still redirects me to my old domain. Is this just a caching issue that will resolve over time, or is there something else I need to do?

Comment: Have you replicated the result on a different browser to validate whether it is a caching issue ?

Comment: Yes I have, the problem still persists

Comment: have you got any errors also would you mind sharing the URL with us.

Answer (score 0):

Under the repository setting you have the section `Github Pages`. There you'll find a way to update the url.

[image]